# Export Keynote to PowerPoint in high resolution

Tags: ms-office, pdf, keynote

When I take a Keynote (5.3 or 6.0) presentation with images (all pasted PDF files), then export the presentation to a PowerPoint presentation, all of the images become severely degraded. For reference, the original PDf files are on the order of 100KB, so I don't believe they are particularly large…

Is there a way to change this behavior? Having to copy each image over by hand greatly reduces the utility of the export feature. Is there possibly some Terminal command that I can set to make the exports high-quality? I need to export this in PPT so that my advisor can edit the file.

Cross-posted from Apple Discussions [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6025821).

EDIT

Though this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91708/how-to-not-compress-inserted-pictures-in-powerpoint-2011-for-mac?rq=1) (*How to not compress inserted pictures in Powerpoint 2011*) seems related, my presentation images are degraded the very first time I open the exported presentation, and viewing the presentation does not improve the resolution.

Comment: I do know that PDFs in Keynote stay distinct PDF files, and I could imagine that the conversion process to Powerpoint will convert the vector data to pixel graphics. Could it be that PPT does not support embedding PDF "natively"?

Comment: Does the problem occur with images that are not in "pdf" format (jpeg, png, tiff, etc.)?

Comment: @KevinGrabher It does seem that placing a rasterized (PNG in this case) image in the Keynote document results in a PPT export with the same quality image. However, I'd like to keep the objects as vector graphics simply for resizability (they graphics are generated in Mathematica, and I'm not always certain what the target application size will be). Any ideas on Keynote's vector graphics options for PPT exports?

Comment: @myhd, I don't believe that PPT handles vector images well, but I'm surprised that the resolution on export is as low as it is. I would expect the resolution to be taken from the image container size in Keynote. Also, thanks for the edits… those were some pretty appalling typos!

Comment: Maybe use svg or something like that? Is that supported by both? I'm not too office-savvy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there doesn't seem to be any way to make PowerPoint handle vector graphics, the only solution is to export the image to the correctly sized PDF image (essentially treating it the same way one might work with a raster image).

While this is incredibly dissatisfying, it does result in a PPT presentation with unpixelated images…

Comment: And huge file size, at least in my case. My company doesn't purchase Acrobat, though, so my only option.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - here is my workaround. Export Keynote as PDF. In Acrobat Pro - export your PDF as Powerpoint. Worked surprisingly well and all vector graphics remain vector.